# Read arguments of a Flask Web service

Tags: python, web-services, flask

I have a very very basic Flask application, to which I am sending 3 parameters that I want to display. However my problem is that the application is getting only the first parameter, it cannot read the values for the other two. Here is my code:

```
  from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
  def listapp():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    runID = request.args.get('runID')
    tweetID = request.args.get('TweetID')
    tweet = request.args.get('Tweet')

    return "Run id: " + str(runID) + " tweetID:" + str(tweetID) + " tweet content:" + str(tweet)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What I get back when calling it as

```
 curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/test?runID=5&TweetID=23&Tweet=6532
```

is

```
Run id: 5 tweetID:None tweet content:None
```

How can I read the values for the last two parameters? Also it is weird that when I am printing the length of request.args I keep on getting 1. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having is not with Flask, it's with your curl command. When you run your curl command the terminal is seeing the `&` as the end of the command. You need to quote the url to get past that:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test?runID=5&TweetID=23&Tweet=6532"
```

Comment: As a follow-up to this question: now I am also trying to set the response of the webservice: return Response(body, status=200, mimetype='text/plain; charset=utf-8')  and when I try to call it in CURL as curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test?runID=5&TweetID=23&Tweet=6532" I get "Method not allowed". Am I calling it wrong again?

Comment: The only method you have allowed is POST. If I'm reading it right, you're now trying to do a GET request.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Added GET and it works perfectly! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You tell it to POST, but are passing GET params.

Try `curl --data "runID=5&TweetID=23&Tweet=6532" http://127.0.0.1:5000/test`  instead.